# How YouTube fullscreen mode works on iPhone Safari?

Tags: javascript

I know fullscreen API does not work on iPhone Safari. But how do sites like YouTube use fullscreen?

Comment: Not sure about youtube but the default fullscreen function will require `webkit` prefix on Safari in IOS. As per https://caniuse.com/?search=requestFullscreen

Answer (score -1):

Fullscreen also works iPhone Safari You require webkit prefix on Safari

Using JS

Create a Function that makes full screen

```
const fullScreen = (invoker) => {
  const fullscreenElement = document.fullscreenElement || document.webkitFullscreenElement;
  if (!fullscreenElement) {
    if (invoker.requestFullscreen) { invoker.requestFullscreen() }
    else if (invoker.webkitRequestFullscreen) { invoker.webkitRequestFullscreen() }
  } else {
    f (document.exitFullscreen) { document.exitFullscreen() }
    else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) { document.webkitExitFullscreen()}
  }
}
```

Now You can call on any event listener

```
const el = document.querySelector("div.vid");
el.addEventListener('dblclick', () => {
   fullScreen(el);
})
```

Comment: It unfortunately doesn't work on nor macos safari nor ios safari